# Wildcard/Javascript solution for coffeescript wildcard

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, url-rewriting, wildcard

I am parsing in CoffeeScript:

```
employee.image = "http://example.com/employee_images/"string.match +employee.firstName + '_' + employee.lastName+".jpg
```

The problem becomes when people upload a photo with .JPG file extension.  When they do this I get a 404.

Turning off case sensitivity on the server is out of the question.

Is there a JavaScript or CoffeeScript solution to just grab any file name with the convention `employee.firstName+'_'_employee.lastName+"`

Comment: *trows a stab* How about you use `.replace('.JPG', '.jpg')` in the `employee.image` object?

Comment: Why aren't you normalizing the filenames on the server? How do you expect the client to know what the proper extension is? What if they send in a PNG? Or a GIF? Or even a `.html` or `.js` file?

Comment: I'm not normalizing on the server as it is a legacy system that will break if I normalize. Not my system, just using images from it.

Comment: The replace string won't work as there is nothing to replace since it is a static URL not polling the server. I am thinking of using an array called filetype as I didn't consider there may be many filetypes.